# UFT 14.03 is Not identifying (& Not recording) Web Chrome Beta 72 objects

Tags: windows, google-chrome, hp-uft

OS: windows 7, windows 10.

UFT 14.03 Not identifying (& Not recording) Chrome Beta 72.0.3626.64.

UFT 14.03 works well with Chrome 71.

I tried following:

1. to install UFT 14.03 patch 3
2. Turn to ON UFT extension (Version 14.3.3791.3) status (in chrome)
3. Restart chrome
4. reinstall chrome, extension
5. restart UFT
6. re-install UFT, patches 1,3
7. enable chrome://flags

   - "Touch events API":   set it to "Enabled"
   - "User Activation V2": set it to "Enabled"

Not yet UFT identifying chrome 72 objects

UFT identify as

```
Browser("Google").WinObject("Chrome Legacy Window")
```

`WinObject` is an `StdWindows` object.

I expect UFT will identify web objects (`WebEdit`, `Webbuton`), like

```
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("Search").Set
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the beta version of Chrome, I've reported the issue and it's under investigation. Please use the latest official release of Chrome (for now at least).

Comment: @Motti: now I also have received from Micro Focus Community that it's under investigation, and waiting for the issue fix. [link](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing-User/UFT-14-03-not-recognizing-Google-Chrome-Beta-72/td-p/1682572)